# How to wait for BroadcastReceiver to receive the message in a Expresso Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, broadcastreceiver, android-espresso

The Expresso doesn't wait for the message to be delivered, resulting that the interface is not updated before asserts to the action are performed.
How to force it to wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no way to force express to wait in this case, or at least, i could find it. The solution i found is to send synchronous messages using method `sendBroadcastSync` instead of `sendBroadcast`.

To avoid smelly code, i wrapped the LocalBroadcastManager in an abstraction  and replaced the wrapper by a mocked version of it in the test, so it can have a different behavior for testing.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I was doing some instrumentation tests and using Mockito to spy on the `BroadcastReceiver` and capture the `Intent`s passed in the `onReceive` method and verify - this works, but still feel this should be easier, or at least a framework standard way to test.

Comment: I think the problem is how the test framework is design. It hold on premise that when the thread is in idle state the application reach a final state.  Asynchronous calls like broadcast can put the thread in idle state before the app complete reacts to test stimulus